# jQuery if/else based on input value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a list of questions that a person can answer yes or no to. At the end, I want to display the question, whether they answered yes or no, and a paragraph about the results. I'm having trouble getting my if/else statement to work.

HTML:

```
<ol>
        <li id='q1'>
           <span>Are any of your valuables visible from the street?</span>
            <input type="checkbox" class="calc" name="street" value="-1" /> yes
            <input type="checkbox" class="calc" name="street" value="1" /> no
            <input type="checkbox" name="street" value="0" /> n/a
        </li>
</ol>

<div class='darkBtn' id='results'>Get Results ></div>
```

JS:

```
$('#results').click(function(){
    var q1 = $('li#q1 input:checkbox:checked.calc').val();

    if (q1 == 1) {
        console.log("You answered No");
    } else {
        console.log("You answered Yes");
    }
});
```

I've tried every variation I can think of, but the console always prints out "You answered Yes".

Comment: Yes sorry I forgot to add that in, but I did try adding that in my code and still didn't get the right results

Comment: Why are you passing the value to jQuery? Simply use it `q1 == 1`.

Comment: Are you sure you want checkboxes here, too? This looks like you should be using radio buttons.

Comment: I didn't design it so it's checkboxes for now, although radio buttons makes more sense to me too

Comment: @Vohuman I did a bad job of proofreading what I posted - I did originally have q1 == 1, I've just tried to many variations that what I meant to post got mixed up. I've tried the exact code I now have posted above, it still isn't working

Comment: You should also be using <label> elements so the user can click on the yes/no word instead of the tiny target that the checkbox or radio button is :) Please, for the good of us all.

Comment: try this : http://jsfiddle.net/d5nh84b5/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you mean to use radio buttons instead of checkboxes. I put together a quick fiddle of your example using radio buttons.

```
$(function(){
    $("#results").click(function(){     
        var val = $('input[name=street]:checked').val();
        if(val == 1) {
            console.log('no');
        } else {
            console.log('yes');
        }
    });
});
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/r8530wsj/4/)

Comment: Thank you! That seems to work - are the radio buttons making that much difference? I didn't design the page so I can't change from checkboxes to radio without getting it approved (stupid, I know)

Comment: It can be done with checkboxes too. Do you want your users to be able to select more than one answer? If not, that's all you should need to get your approval...

Answer (score 0):

First your checkboxes should not have the same `name` attribute.

Then you should grab the selected questions using:

```
$('li#q1 input[type="checkbox"].calc:checked')
```

Also it appears that you want radio boxes instead of check boxes, in which case you'd be able to use the same `name`

UPDATE: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ze0qbxzb/)

Comment: I tried making those changes and it's still not working.

Comment: I was about to make a fiddle but it looks like @Antiga did already, if that does not fit your needs lemme know...

Comment: well, added a fiddle anyway, which is working with checkboxes: http://jsfiddle.net/ze0qbxzb/